# UICollectionView Exception Crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, datasource, uicollectionview

I have a mystery problem with `UICollectionView`.

I add my collection view to my tableview cell like so:

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout = [UICollectionViewFlowLayout new];
                layout.scrollDirection = UICollectionViewScrollDirectionHorizontal;

                UICollectionView *collection = [[UICollectionView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, 100) collectionViewLayout:layout];
                [collection setDataSource:self];
                [collection setDelegate:self];
                [collection setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
                [collection registerClass:[UICollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
                collection.tag = kTagPhotoCollectionView;
                [cell.contentView addSubview:collection];
```

I'm implementing all the necessary delegate and data source methods and you can see I've set the datasource and delegate and have implemented them in my header.

When I go and press a `UIButton` which displays a `UIImagePickerController` and the app crashes with this error:

```
2013-08-13 20:17:02.578 [619:60b] *** Assertion failure in -[PUCollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2891/UICollectionView.m:1397
2013-08-13 20:17:35.502 Sparky[619:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView dataSource is not set'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x30a02ed3 0x3aa2b6c7 0x30a02da5 0x3138c72f 0x3305f647 0x32f4adf9 0x32f47139 0x32eea543 0x32b72feb 0x32b6e817 0x32b6e6a9 0x32b6e0bd 0x32b6decf 0x32b67bfd 0x309cdf71 0x309cb8ff 0x309cbc4b 0x30936541 0x30936323 0x353ca343 0x32f4f8a5 0x5f835 0x3af40ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

I have set the datasource, so I have no idea why this would occur.

Comment: What is PUCollectionView? The error cites that, but I don't see any use of it in your code?

Comment: I have no idea what it is. I assume its some hidden class Apple uses behind the scenes.

Comment: If you comment out all the code in the button method that presents the image picker, does it still crash? Could it be that your controller (the collection view's delegate) is being deallocated?

Comment: Well, your getting me somewhere. Why might that be the case though when I am only presenting view controller over the existing one? Suggestions? Thanks for the help thus far.

Comment: I don't know, you need to describe what controllers you have, and how you get them on screen. You can check if it's being deallocated, just implement dealloc and put a log statement in it.

Comment: Starting to think this is something else. Just slowly started eliminating UICollectionView code to see what the cause was. I have no removed all related code as though a UICollectionView never existed. Cleaned the build, deleted from iPhone, re-built, restarted Xcode and computer and iPhone but that error still pops up. WHHHA? Somehow it must be retaining data from an old build, how might I thoroughly build my pap from fresh?

Answer (score 5):

I faced with the similar problem, but my app crashed after I programmatically pop my UICollectionViewController. In some reason (I think it's just a bug in SDK) self.collectionView was alive after its' controller destroy, thus causing this failure:

```
*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _createPreparedSupplementaryViewForElementOfKind:atIndexPath:withLayoutAttributes:applyAttributes:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-2935.137/UICollectionView.m:1305
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'UICollectionView dataSource is not set'
```

The solution is just override -dealloc in UICollectionViewController and release self.collectionView manually. ARC code:

```
- (void)dealloc {

    self.collectionView = nil;
}
```

Hope this will save time for somebody.